# Is my data right censored or right truncated?

Tags: survival, censoring, truncation

I have a dataset of the percent of pavement area that is cracked and time as the explanatory variable for a city's streets. Engineering principles and logic tell us that as that as time progresses, the percent cracking keeps increasing.

This is what my data looks like:
[image: Percent pavement area cracked versus age of pavement]

As you can see, there's a huge variation in the cracking observed for any given time. But my concern is that as pavements get older and the cracking gets to an uncomfortable degree, they get maintained and treated by the city and only a few cases with low cracking ever make it to over 25 years and get included in the dataset. This skews my regression because it makes it seem like pavements with a higher age should have lower cracking, which is not accurate.

So in the context of the above information, I need to figure out if my data is right truncated or right censored? My understanding was that it is "randomly right censored" where some datasets stop "participating in the study for unknown reasons". And I was treating my pavements which got maintained as those random datasets which are not participating anymore. Is my understanding of this concept correct?

Comment: With random censoring points or random truncation points (rather than fixed thresholds), you generally can't tell if they're present *by looking at the data alone*. External information is required (at the least you need something to compare what you observe to).  In this case you know it happens; you'd want to get hold of the maintenance times and try to use that in a model for how cracking increases over time.